# MCP2551 with STM32 MCU

Tags: stm32, can, transceiver

im learning about the CAN protocol, and bought the transceiver module MCP2551 like this:

[image]

I made the driver for CAN controller first in loopback mode for debug, im sending the numbers 1,2,3 and 4 with 1s of interval. Without the transceiver connected to the microcontroller, messages are sent correctly, for example when the number 2 is sent with an ID of 0xff;

[image]

But when i connect the transceiver to the mcu, the message is corrupted:
[image]

So i think that is something related to the transceiver itself, it is not a driver problem, I checked the connections and everything is fine, has anyone had this problem to help me?

The peripheral connection is below:
[image]

There is one more connection thas is not in the image which is the gnd of STM with gnd of arduino, but the problem is before, because i have not tested the CAN in normal mode but in loopback. I think that the problem is (PA12, CTx) AND (PA11, CRx) connection or with the transceiver. This is more likely.

Comment: Can you show a diagram? Are you using terminating resistors?

Comment: Its a STM32F407VET

Comment: Is Vcc 5V? This part can't handle 3V3 levels.

Comment: And why are there 3 resistors on the board? What purpose do they fill? Can you post a proper schematic?